# Providing variables values to a module while calling it

Tags: terraform

I have a followed directory structure:

```
|   main.tf
|   module.tf
|   terraform.tf
|   terraform.tfvars

\---modules
    \---org_bd
        \---resource
                resource.tf
                providers.tf
```

The `module/org_bd/resrouce/provider.tf` contains:

```
provider "boundary" {
  api_key = var.api_key
  app_key = var.app_key
}
```

And these values are declared and defined inside `./terraform.tf` and `./terraform.tfvars`:
However, while trying to plan or validate it gives following error:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared input variable

  on modules\org_bd\resrouce\providers.tf line 13, in provider " boundary":
  13:   api_key = var.api_key

An input variable with the name "api_key" has not been declared. This variable
can be declared with a variable "api_key" {} block.
```

As I understand, this is happening because the variable used inside the module are defined outside of it. But I believe its possible that you can provide values from outside to a module while calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing variables to modules is done at the point of invocation. For example (from a project I currently have open:

```
module "workers" {
  source              = "./modules/workers"
  depends_on          = [module.vpc.dns_record]
  vpc                 = module.vpc.vpc
  az                  = module.vpc.az
  zone                = module.vpc.zone
  bastion_sg_id       = module.bastion.bastion_sg_id
  control_plane_sg_id = module.control_plane.control_plane_sg_id

  name             = var.name
  owner            = var.owner
  project          = var.project
  env              = var.env
  workspace        = var.workspace
  key_name         = var.key_name
  public_key_path  = var.public_key_path
  private_key_path = var.private_key_path
  instance_type    = var.worker_type
  aws_region       = var.region
}
```

Apart from `source` and `depends_on`, which are built-in properties, on the left of the assignments are the input property names and on the right are the values.

Input variables are declared within the module in a file named something like `variables.tf`, though, in my modules I call this `input.tf` because the name is arbitrary and I think that `input` is more meaningful and matches the common `output.tf` that declares output properties.

This example also shows how to use the output of modules. These are normally declared in a file named `output.tf` (or something like that). Also shown is the use of variables at this level, they are declared in my top-level `input.tf` and I've provided values in `variables.auto.tfvars`, which is a special filename recognised by terraform that is automatically loaded without having to specify a var-file option on the command-line.

Comment: Thankyou, understood. But is there a way I can use a single/central variable file in multiple modules. Since there are some common variables which will be used across modules and I find it ugly to define them again and again at different places?

Comment: No. Modules are meant to be independent of each other. The closest you can get is to have a common vars file and copy it into your modules - all tf files in a directory are merged so you can have multiple var definition files in that way.